# Is consistency among classifiers a good measure for feature sets?

Tags: svm, cart, model-evaluation, feature-engineering

I have two feature extraction approaches (or feature sets) to describe the same data, the feature set 1 has overall consistent results among 4 different classifiers (SVM, Logistic Regression, Adaboost and CART), all between 44.7-56.0% F1 on testing data; and the feature set 2 has very different results among the 4 classifiers, especally for CART (56.4% F1), SVM (38.1% F1) and Logistic Regression (23.5% F1 only) on the same testing data.

Can I say that feature set 1 is better than feature set 2 because of consistency among classifiers, although feature set 2 achieved best F1 (56.4% with CART)?

Many thanks!

Comment: This very much depends on your data. It may be that the second set of variables is of a particular nature, for ex. time series data, so using certain methods may impose an unfair disadvantage.